# PHP delete database from SQL using button

Tags: php, sql, sql-delete

I need to delete news articles from database using a delete button. I have written all the code but it gives me error Notice: Undefined index: acticleID in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\PortalZaVijesti\php\delete.php on line 5. I don't see what is wrong so can you look at my code?
Admin.php

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "news_portal") or die(mysql_error());
        $query = "SELECT * FROM news_site;";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<p>".$row['title']; 
            echo "</p>
                <form action='php/delete.php' method='post' class='deletePHP'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='articleID' value='".$row['id']."'/>
                    <input type='submit' name='delete' value='delete'/>
                </form>;
```

delete.php

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "news_portal") or die(mysql_error());
    if(isset($_POST["delete"]) && !empty($_POST["articleID"])){
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST["acticleID"]);
    }

    $delquery = "DELETE FROM news_site WHERE ID='$id'";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $delquery) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)){
        echo "It was really successful.";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a typing error in delete.php.

On line 3 of the code shown, "articleID" is spelt as "acticleID". This is why you are getting an Undefined index.

Change:

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST["acticleID"]);
```

to:

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST["articleID"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please fix the line

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST["acticleID"]);
```

to

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST["articleID"]);
```

You have mistyped the articleId